# What could cause "PROCEDURE schema.identity does not exist" using MySQL and Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Using Java, Hibernate, and MySQL I persist instances of a class like this using the Hibernate support from Spring.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

  private Long id;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

This generally works fine. But now and then when trying to persist such an entity, I get this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: PROCEDURE schema.identity does not exist
```

The underlying MySQL error is:

```
SQL Error: 1305, SQLState: 42000
```

This is a regular MySQL error described in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_sp_does_not_exist).

My problem is that this system worked for months without any problem. Only recently I discovered the error described above. Do you have any ideas what could have caused this problem? What does Hibernate look for and doesn't find?

If this question should be on serverfault, feel free to migrate it :)

Comment: I didn't solve the underlying problem but restarting the Tomcat at least made them disapear :) It looks like the MySQL server was upgraded and Hibernate somehow lost track. Please vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

In this post:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,96721,96721#msg-96721

They had the same type of errors and fixed it buy upgrading their MySQL connector to the latest one, but that was back in 2007.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Identity() is a h2 specific database function that some framework code tries to trigger via sql.
MySql does not know it, so it throws the BadSyntax Exception.

If you happen to use Spring Security with acl support, like me, then
JdbcMutableAclService is the problem.
The java-docs state:

> "The default settings are for HSQLDB. If you are using a different
>   database you  will probably need to set the sidIdentityQuery(String)
>   and  classIdentityQuery(String) classIdentityQuery properties
>   appropriately".

Those   values default to "call identity()", which is unknown by MySql.
The new right values are stated by
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56275135/9027032)

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same exception today and found this post helped. 
The problem I had is that I started tomcat first but failed to start the mysql. After I started mysql, the app worked for most of the part but failed to insert a record with above exception. Restarted tomcat resolved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too with spring hibernate and MySQL...
I think the error appear not alway but sometime if the tomcat server,
so i fixed the problem only restarting the tomcat server with MySQL on.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this issue. Ensure you have configured the right hibernate dialect for your sql version.
I changed:

```
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
```

to

```
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
```

And it worked for me.
My Sql version is 5.7 and that was the right dialect

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL5Dialect.html