# Spring Security Acl object

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-security, acl

My service to create Acl is like this:

```
@Autowired
JdbcMutableAclService aclService;

public void createAcl(AclDTO aclDTO) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    ObjectIdentity oi = new ObjectIdentityImpl(getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(aclDTO.getClassPath()),
        aclDTO.getObjectIdentityId());
    Sid sid = new PrincipalSid(aclDTO.getSid());

    Permission p = getPermission(aclDTO.getPermissionDesc());

    // Create or update the relevant ACL
    MutableAcl acl = null;
    try {
        acl = (MutableAcl) this.aclService.readAclById(oi);
    } catch (NotFoundException nfe) {
        acl = aclService.createAcl(oi);
    }

    // Now grant some permissions via an access control entry (ACE)
    acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().size(), p, sid, true);
    this.aclService.updateAcl(acl);
}
```

But it seems something wrong with this class and when it runs, I got the error like this:

> 2019-02-25 11:02:18.410 ERROR 10608 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.s.s.acl.aop.logging.LoggingAspect      : Exception in com.spring.security.acl.service.AccessGrantService.createAcl() with cause = 'com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: PROCEDURE security_acl.identity does not exist' and exception = 'StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [call identity()]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: PROCEDURE security_acl.identity does not exist'
>
> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [call identity()]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: PROCEDURE security_acl.identity does not exist
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:93)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1398)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:388)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:446)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:467)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
>       at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService.createOrRetrieveSidPrimaryKey(JdbcMutableAclService.java:262)
>       at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService.createOrRetrieveSidPrimaryKey(JdbcMutableAclService.java:237)
>       at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService.createObjectIdentity(JdbcMutableAclService.java:171)
>       at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService.createAcl(JdbcMutableAclService.java:118)
>       at com.spring.security.acl.service.AccessGrantService.createAcl(AccessGrantService.java:37)
>       at com.spring.security.acl.service.AccessGrantService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8f8e3af4.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
>       at com.spring.security.acl.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
>       at com.spring.security.acl.service.AccessGrantService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$802d4181.createAcl()
>       at com.spring.security.acl.web.rest.AclResource.updateAcl(AclResource.java:24)
>       at com.spring.security.acl.web.rest.AclResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bf5f9ed6.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
>       at com.spring.security.acl.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
>       at com.spring.security.acl.web.rest.AclResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e0281d5.updateAcl()
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:884)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at com.spring.security.acl.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:38)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:65)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>       at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:336)
>       at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: PROCEDURE security_acl.identity does not exist
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2491)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2449)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1381)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeQuery(ProxyStatement.java:111)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyStatement.java)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:433)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376)
>       ... 164 common frames omitted

I'll appreciate if someone can help me deal with this!

Comment: The required configuration for each database engine is given in the reference documentation.

Answer (score 8):

It seem that you are using MySQL.

I had the same error and resolved it by setting up the JdbcMutableAclService as below:

```
// Based on https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-security-acl/src/main/java/org/baeldung/acl/config/ACLContext.java
@Bean
public JdbcMutableAclService aclService() {
  JdbcMutableAclService jdbcMutableAclService = new JdbcMutableAclService(dataSource, lookupStrategy(), aclCache());

  // TODO: for MySQL ONLY
  jdbcMutableAclService.setClassIdentityQuery("SELECT @@IDENTITY");
  jdbcMutableAclService.setSidIdentityQuery("SELECT @@IDENTITY");

  return jdbcMutableAclService;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Ran into the same problem today and your answer was of great help.

Answer (score 5):

Solution for PostgreSQL when use `JdbcMutableAclService`:

```
@Bean
public MutableAclService aclService() {
    JdbcMutableAclService aclService = new JdbcMutableAclService(dataSource, lookupStrategy(), aclCache());
    aclService.setSidIdentityQuery("SELECT currval('acl_sid_id_seq')");
    aclService.setClassIdentityQuery("SELECT currval('acl_class_id_seq')");
    return aclService;
}
```

Comment: The sequence always starts with `1`. Anyway to ensure it starts with last used sequence number.